# c++ class disassembly

Tags: c++, class, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
int x,y;
Base() { x=10; y=20; }
virtual void myfunction() { }
};

int main() {
Base *b = new Base();
return 0;
}
```

The disassembly gives me something like:

```
push 0Ch                ; size of Base
call j_<some giberrish> ; IDA gives the comment "operator new(uint)"
add esp, 4              ; function epilogue
mov [ebp+var_E0], eax
```

A few lines later you have the constructor being called.

```
mov ecx, [ebp+var_E0]
call j_Base__Base
mov [ebp+var_F4], eax
```

- At first I had thought that `var_E0` would contain the pointer to the instance, but now I'm pretty sure that `var_F4` does as it contains the return value of the constructor.
- In that case, what does `var_E0` contain at all? Why is it moved into `ecx` before the constructor is called?

Comment: um, why would that be loaded into ecx before a call to the constructor? :/

Comment: @uki it's the `this` pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a debug build you're looking at and debug builds are very conservative with what they do. Creating an object is a two stage process: allocate memory and then construct the object. Your compiler is putting the allocated memory pointer into a temporary variable. If you build an optimised version, this temporary variable won't be stored since that introduces an unnecessary overhead (writing/reading RAM).

Comment: Just to clarify, the first call allocates memory and not the call to j_Base__Base, correct?
Thanks!

Comment: @eQuiNoX - Like Skizz says, the compiler must do this in separate steps, allocate memory and then construct the object. In the worst case, when construction fails, it must also call `operator delete` to release the memory. That's a good reason for saving the pointer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's some internal variable for a compiler generated temporary.

When you write `new Base`, the compiler generates a call to the global
`operator new` function, then calls the constructor on the returned
address.  Apparently, your compiler saves the address returned from
`operator new` in memory, rather than keeping it in a register.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ uses an internal convention where constructors return the pointer to the object instance (by C++ standard, constructors don't have a return value). So in your case both var_E0 *and* var_F4 hold the instance pointer.

Check [my article](https://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) for more details on how Visual C++ implements C++.